# How do I force a string to have both digits and alpha chars with regexp

Tags: regex, validation

I am trying to have a regexp to force/validate A string to have both digits (numbers) and alpha chars `(a-zA-Z)`.
doing `[a-zA-Z0-9]` will allow any combination (including only digits or only letters).
The order has to be random.
I do not know how to force "stuff" in such a case.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use lookaheads for this. Consider this regex:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

It has 2 lookaheads for forcing presence of digit and alphabet.

```
(?=.*[0-9])    # assert that there is at least a digit ahead
(?=.*[a-zA-Z]) # assert that there is at least an alphabet ahead
[a-zA-Z0-9]+$  # will match only alphanumerics
```

[Regex Lookaround Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Note that if your regex tool/language doesn't support lookaheads then you will have to use **alternation**:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*?([0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Comment: Note this will allow also &&password1, While I want to force only letters and numbers.

Comment: Oh ok in that case let me update the regex

Comment: Using what anubhava posted, does this work? `^([0-9]?[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]?[0-9])[\w\d]*$`